# GWT gilead problem

Tags: gwt, gilead

I am getting lots of difficulty in integrating gilead in gwt. Can
someone please send the jars they have successfully used that works
because the one I have downloaded does not work
Please someone help me with this gilead and GWT, it makes one full day that i
trying to integrate gilead into gwt with no success!!! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What problems are you having?

I'm using hibernate4gwt

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.hibernate4gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate4gwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can u tell me all the configuration from adding jars, eiditing app.get.xml and ... that needs to be made to integrate gilead into gwt.

Comment: if someone could me the jars they are using successfully  at bakenoor@gmail.com, then it would be very nice

Comment: @noor go to maven central website and download them from there.